# Can't see enum value

Tags: rust

I'm trying to recreate the way error handling is done in `std::io`. I'm basing my code on [this](http://www.hydrocodedesign.com/2014/05/28/practicality-with-rust-error-handling/) article.

My problem is that I've put my code in a separate `mod` and now I can't see the enum value I want to return. Code sample:

```
mod error {
    use std::str::SendStr;

    pub type ProgramResult<T> = Result<T, ProgramError>;

    #[deriving(Show)]
    pub struct ProgramError {
        kind: ProgramErrorKind,
        message: SendStr
    }

    /// The kinds of errors that can happen in our program.
    /// We'll be able to pattern match against these.
    #[deriving(Show)]
    pub enum ProgramErrorKind {
        Configuration
    }

    impl ProgramError {
        pub fn new<T: IntoMaybeOwned<'static>>(msg: T, kind: ProgramErrorKind) -> ProgramError {
            ProgramError {
                kind: kind,
                message: msg.into_maybe_owned()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I cannot see `Configuration` anywhere else in my code, even though the enum is public and duly imported in all other mods that try to use this. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you do `use error::Configuration` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using the module resolution operator when attempting to reference the `enum` types? For instance, here's an example that works fine:

```
mod error {
    #[deriving(Show)]
    pub enum ProgramErrorKind {
        Configuration,
        SomethingElse
    }
}

fn main() {
    // You can import them locally with 'use'
    use error::Configuration;

    let err = Configuration;

    // Alternatively, use '::' directly
    let res = match err {
        error::Configuration => "Config error!",
        error::SomethingElse => "I have no idea.",
    };
    println!("Error type: {}", res);
}
```

Comment: I thought importing ProgramErrorKind was enough?

Comment: @lapinrigolo `use error::{ProgramErrorKind, Configuration, SomethingElse};` is what you want.